# Iterate through a sized Range<T> by borrowing it

Tags: rust, range, iteration, immutability, borrow

Iterating through a `Range<T>` seems to consume the range instance as `into_iter` function takes the ownership of the range. By looking at the [documentation of range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#blanket-implementations), it is clear that the `Borrow` trait is only implemented for dynamic range objects. Without cloning, would it be possible to iterate through a range while also passing immutable references of the range to other functions?

```rust
let numbers = 500..4000;

// ERROR [(E0277)]: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::ops::Range<i32>`
for n in &numbers {
    println!("{}", n);

    do_something_else(&numbers);
    reuse_range(&numbers);
}

// Surprisingly, there are no errors when it comes to argument type of functions.
fn do_something_else(range: &Range<i32>) { }
fn reuse_range(range: &Range<i32>) { }
```

As seen above, functions can take a borrow of `Range<T: Sized>` but the compiler itself does not allow borrowing ranges.

So far I have tried using `Box` smart pointer but the behaviour is the same.
Simply, `by_ref()` is available, but that would also restrict us from borrowing as immutable since we already would have a mutable borrow of the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at the implementations:

[`Range` implements `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator). `for` loops desugar to a call to [`std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which is [implemented for everything which is already an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-25) (since you can obviously create an iterator from an iterator -- just return the iterator). Additionally, [`Iterator` is implemented for (and only for) `&mut` references to existing iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13).

From this we can deduce the error:

- You can iterator over anything which implements `IntoIterator`.
- You can turn any `Iterator` into an `Iterator` through `IntoIterator`. Which does nothing.
- `Iterator` is only implemented for unique (`&mut`) references to other `Iterator`s.

Hence, you can't iterator over `&Range`s, and instead only over `&mut Range`s, or `Range`s.

What should be done instead is to either [`Clone` the `Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Clone):

```
let my_range = 10..40;
for i in my_range.clone() {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

Take a mutable reference to the range (thereby emptying it too):

```
let mut my_range = 10..40;

for i in &mut my_range {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}

assert_eq!(my_range.next(), None);
```

Or do the more idiomatic action of just building the range each time:

```
for i in 10..40 {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

Which is extremely cheap to do.

---

Additionally, these rules about implementations of the `Iterator` trait for `&mut` and not `&` references apply to all iterators. This allows for us to do something like this:

```
let mut my_iter = 0..100;

// Only take first 50 elements.
for x in (&mut my_iter).take(50) {
    println!("{:?} < 50", x);
}

for x in my_iter {
    println!("{:?} >= 50", x);
}
```

Note that [`take` takes `self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take), however `self` is `&mut Range`, so we don't use up the original `Range`.